# React-Native - RangeError appears when trying to inject splash screen image

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to inject a splash screen image on to my app but I keep getting error message: **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** Project is react-native-cli, could that be the issue?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject("stores")
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { stores, navigation } = this.props;
        setTimeout (() => {
            navigation.navigate("Login")
        }, stores.config.SplashTime)
    }
    render() {
        const { stores } = this.props
        return ( 
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Image style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}} source={stores.config.SplashIMG}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the props? Report: ```Running "appName" with {"rootTag": 11,"initialProps":{}}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed img link to require and amended component to DidUpdate.

````
componentDidUpdate() {
     const { stores, navigation } = this.props;
     console.log(this.props)
     setTimeout (() => {
         navigation.navigate("Login")
     }, stores.config.SplashTime)
 }
 render() {
     const { stores } = this.props
     return ( 
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         <Image style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}} source={require('../../images/splash.jpg')}/>
         </View>)
 }
}```
````